# How to "conditionally" remove newlines with sed or awk etc?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

Given a file that contains multiple lines, some with `=` at the very end.

I wish to join each line ending with `=` with the next line.  Any other newlines should remain untouched.

I have been unable to do this, because `sed` seems to operate on a line-by-line basis, thus always "adds" a newline back.

Example input:

```
Apple
Banana milkshake
Cherry =
Pie
```

Should become:

```
Apple
Banana milkshake
Cherry Pie
```

I am totally open to using tools other than `sed`/`awk`.

Comment: Just in case this is about quoted printable, consider using an off the shelf program like [qprint](http://www.fourmilab.ch/webtools/qprint/)

Comment: You are correct @Olaf, thankyou for that pertinent pointer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk '{ORS = sub(/=$/,"") ? "" : "\n"} 1' file
Apple
Banana milkshake
Cherry Pie
```

Using a conditional expression, we set `ORS` (output record separator, default: newline) to either the empty string or the newline. `sub()` is true when a replacement has been done at the end of the line, removing an existing `=`, otherwise it's false. In the first case we set `ORS` to `""`, or else to `"\n"`. `1` means print the line (using the `ORS` value selected for every line).

---

Alternatively, we could use GNU `sed` and zero separation, assuming the file is not huge and small enough for the memory:

```
sed -z 's/=\n//g' file
```

`sed` reads the whole file as one line, and globally replaces `=\n` with nothing.

Answer (score 7):

Using `sed` to detect lines that end with `=`.  When such a line is found, the next line is appended to the current line in the editing buffer with a newline character separating the two, the `=` and the newline character are removed, and the joined line is printed.

```
$ cat file
Apple
Banana milkshake
Cherry =
Pie
```

```
$ sed '/=$/ { N; s/=\n//; }' file
Apple
Banana milkshake
Cherry Pie
```

Note that this does not cope with multiple consecutive lines all ending with `=`.  To deal with them, the process has to be repeated (intermediate results could be saved to a temporary file, to the original file, or simply piped to the same command again).

... or you could do an explicit loop in `sed`:

```
sed -e ':again' -e '/=$/ { N; s/=\n//' -e 'b again' -e '}' file
```

Testing:

```
$ cat file
Apple
Banana milkshake
Pie =
with a cherry =
on top
```

```
$ sed -e ':again' -e '/=$/ { N; s/=\n//' -e 'b again' -e '}' file
Apple
Banana milkshake
Pie with a cherry on top
```

Answer (score 3):

sed:

```
sed -e ':a' -e '$!N;s/=\n//;t a' -e 'P;D' file
```

GNU sed:

```
sed ':a;N;s/=\n//;ta;P;D' file
```

GNU awk:

```
awk '1' RS='=\n' ORS= file
```

perl:

```
perl -pe 's/=\n//' file
```

If the last line of input ends with `=<newline>`, awk or perl will remove it, sed won't.

Answer (score 1):

> I wish to join each line ending with = with the next line.

updated

```
awk '/=$/ {line=line $0;sub(/=$/,"",line);next}{$0= line $0;print $0;line=""} END{if (line) print line}' file
Apple
Banana milkshake
Cherry Pie
```

Also tested for joining each line(record) ending with `=` with the next line or joining multiple consecutive lines(records) all ending with `=` with the next line. The line or lines with `=` are at the end of file or not (anywhere)

this code:

- the first part of code (before `next`) joins lines with `=` and saves it in var `line` and `sub()` replaces `=` with `""` or empty string (deletes it).
- the second part (after `next`) joins the content of the var `line` with the next line (i.e., the current record), prints it and assigns empty value to the var.
- the END part prints that record or records with `=` at the end of file.
- The `next` statement. Here the lines that do not match `/=$/` will instead be processed by the second block of code. But, if the file ends with a line (o more lines) with `=`, the second block of code does not execute but we can print that line o lines in the `END` part.

For example, we can taste all this with the following data of a supposed recipe:

```
cat supposed-recipe.txt 
Cherry Pie Smoothie. =
This cherry smoothie =
tastes just like...

Ingredients:
Greek yogurt, plain non-fat, =
unsweetened milk, =
unsalted cashews,  =
etc.

And also:
1 pinch salt, =
and oats.
1 teaspoon =
vanilla extract,
fresh =
lemon juice.
1 teaspoon =
cinnamon, =
and frozen =
sweet cherries.

Optional:
2 teaspoons =
syrup or honey, =
to sweeten if wanted.

...and, if you want,
1 teaspoon chia seeds =
or similar. =
```

```
awk '/=$/ {line=line $0;sub(/=$/,"",line);next}{$0= line $0;print $0;line=""} END{if (line) print line}' supposed-recipe.txt

Cherry Pie Smoothie. This cherry smoothie tastes just like...

Ingredients:
Greek yogurt, plain non-fat, unsweetened milk, unsalted cashews,  etc.

And also:
1 pinch salt, and oats.
1 teaspoon vanilla extract,
fresh lemon juice.
1 teaspoon cinnamon, and frozen sweet cherries.

Optional:
2 teaspoons syrup or honey, to sweeten if wanted.

...and, if you want,
1 teaspoon chia seeds or similar.
```